# Delphi Datamatrix Tamanho estatico

Tags: delphi, qrcode, matriz

Estou trabalhando com Data Matrix estou usando as Unit DataMatrixBarcode, dmtx.

```
var
options:DatamatrixEncodeOptions;

options := InitializeDatamatrixEncodeOptions;
options.moduleSize := 4;
options.marginSize := 10;
options.rotate := 0;
options.scheme := DmtxScheme(2);
options.sizeIdx := DmtxSymbolSize(DmtxSymbol16x16);//DmtxSymbolSize(2-3);
options.mosaic := 0;
EncodeDatamatrix(Funcoes.ColocaZero('Produto:3445Produto:123',imgBarcode.Picture.Bitmap,options);
```

Conforme a quantidade de informações eu tiver dentro da DataMatrix vai variar o seu tamanho, ou seja se eu tiver 20 produtos a DataMatrix fica com um tamanho, se eu tiver 2 produtos vai ter outro tamanho.
Como eu deixo o tamanho estático, por exemplo 100x100?

[Data MatixBarcode](https://github.com/JanOosting/delphidmtx/blob/master/DataMatrixBarcode.pas)
[lib dmtx](https://github.com/JanOosting/delphidmtx)

Comment: Onde está disponivel esse DataMatrixBarcode ?

Comment: Pelo que percebi desse componente, não tem como fazer oque você quer, de forma dinâmica. Posso até estar errado, mas parece que tem uma forma de contornar esta situação, que é marcando o Stretch do TImage que exibe o QRCode. Poderia ver se isso funciona para você ?